# Retrieve list of channels in sony android tv

Tags: sony, android-tv

Is there any way to retrive all the channels list through code in a Sony TV with Android running on it? I would like to get all the channel names and descriptions of every channel and use it on my Android TV application.

Comment: I don't believe third-party apps have access to all of the Live Channel channels and programs, only the ones from that app.